# Exceptions while connecting to the service bus

Tags: azureservicebus

While connecting to signalr that is configured to use the azure service bus, we are getting 502 and 500 errors since a few hours. The connect and abort fail:

https://mmeet.net/signalr/connect?transport=longPolling&clientProtocol=1.4&MeetingId=b7acc652-8a78-4f64-8ad2-af9484b25865&connectionToken=S%2BQSYyz4tSJTk5200dgUDv1csUNBRO7DT5akRRfkKruqYmbx3DD%2BcIiAr7nakWIl9M3347835prU%2FR5w3Fq4F0y3prhDsiqaG3TgiMhKLu69LcxcOF%2BfOE2dWKiBuU%2FUvpflpXutfZ3krnQ6QH5R6w%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22meetinghub%22%7D%5D&tid=8&_=1510676508783

gives a standard 502 error and

https://mmeet.net/signalr/abort?transport=longPolling&clientProtocol=1.4&MeetingId=b7acc652-8a78-4f64-8ad2-af9484b25865&connectionToken=8IZTzSjy%2FVpYXq6Q%2FWHz2S6kPApEaD9uEKLiaLuzGUJtNiihXE69%2F8BfY5hWLVepwxB8Y4I6d9PQS%2BZT0VLrgR6kSrFClShBuaunmiJWmuFD6QHGi0yUgugRsOOOsDEYMpk5cJBVSjHNw6HWr48Fxw%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22meetinghub%22%7D%5D

gives the following exception.

Exception Details: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 50002: Provider Internal Error, Resource:sb://metaphora.servicebus.windows.net/signalr_topic_metaphorasignalr_4/subscriptions/752b0eb8-5797-4781-b729-59a74afa5a7a. TrackingId:e2eb137f-2cac-45d8-b366-fa8585c6c2d2_G39, SystemTracker:metaphora.servicebus.windows.net:SIGNALR_TOPIC_MetaphoraSignalR_4/Subscriptions/752b0eb8-5797-4781-b729-59a74afa5a7a, Timestamp:11/14/2017 4:22:01 PM

Also our topics are gone in the azure service bus admin. Is there a problem with the service bus?

Answer (score 0):

@jan-willem-spuij this is a support question, **not** a question for StackOverflow. If you experience an abnormal behaviour that is not expected at all, then you should direct your question at [Azure support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/support/options/).

In this case, if this is a production issue, I'd not even think twice before opening a support case. If it's lower environment, check with your team as entities, just like energy, don't show up or disappear. You can also try [ServiceBus Explorer tool](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/releases/latest) to inspect your namespace.

For exceptions and troubleshooting with Azure support, you've got `TrackingId`. Add that to your support case to get to the bottom of the issue.

Comment: Funny you should mention that, I get instructions from azure support to create a topic here ;-) Seems they (mis)use it to handle support?

Comment: What can I tell you, common sense is no longer common. Why would you post on a **community forum** a production related issue for example? Or how an internal tracking ID for Azure Service Bus would shed any light here? Just becouse someone says "jump" doesn't mean the follow up should be "how high", right? :)

Comment: Second guessing instructions from support via direct message does not seem very productive when you want an issue resolved. The specific instructions were:

"Interesting. We would like to have an engineer take a look. Could you please post this here: Can you create a forum post with the tag “azureservicebus” and send us the link? http://aka.ms/soforums  and send us the link? We will make sure it gets to the proper channel.  ^RS"

Feel free to ask a moderator to delete the question, it seems a total european outage anyway.

Comment: I'm not going to dive into that specific decision, but Azure support has a decent internal infrastructure to handle these kind of support issues rather than using SO as a ticket management system. Anyways, I've let me know and I'm sure they will assess the approach :)